# How to load Django template after enter similar to facebook?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-templates

What I have been trying to find, with no answer yet, is how I could have a user click on link to a template, then instead of waiting for the whole page to load, allow the user to view what has already loaded while they wait for more load heavy content to arrive, similar to what Facebook does when you first get to a page and see things loading.

There is not much more I can say as the question is pretty self-explanatory. I have checked google and stack overflow.

Comment: You should research "ajax" - your question is too broad though

Answer (score 1):

In order to allow the use to view the loaded page and dynamically view the rest of the page, you use a technology known as AJAX. It allows you to make asynchronous calls to the database, which can be triggered by some JS event(like onscroll) and load the queried data without reloading the entire page.

AJAX in Django is pretty straightforward, though some knowledge of JQuery(or even Javascript) will be required. You may also use the python package `django-dajax` which will make things easier. I think you will find the following links useful:

- [Tango with Django ajax guide](http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book17/chapters/ajax.html) (one of the best, but a bit tough)
- [django-dajax docs](https://django-dajax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the links. I realize the broad scope of the question but had no better way of asking. There isn't a much better way for me to phrase the question as I didn't know what technology to be looking for and lacked the knowledge to be more precise as I'm more of a back end guy.